# How to get the input of a month to match with a case #

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I don't know how to get the input of a month to match with a case #. I kind of get the idea of what to do, but not sure what else to add to my code for it to work.

This is the assignment:

> Write a program that prompts the user for a month name and then uses a switch to display the name of the season. Assume spring months are March, April and May; summer is June, July, August; autumn is September, October, November; winter is December, January, February. You must use a switch. For full points your switch code should demonstrate an economy of statements and it should respond with an error message for bad inputs

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment4 {
    private static Scanner input;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of a month");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        switch (month) {
          case 12: season = "winter"; break;
          case 1: season = "winter"; break;
          case 2: season = "winter"; break;
          case 3: season = "spring"; break;
          case 4: season = "spring"; break;
          case 5: season = "spring"; break;
          case 6: season = "summer"; break;
          case 7: season = "summer"; break;
          case 8: season = "summer"; break;
          case 9: season = "fall"; break;
          case 10: season = "fall"; break;
          case 11: season = "fall"; break;
          default: System.out.println("Error: invalid month.");
}
        System.out.println("The season of the month " + month + "is " + season + ".");
}}
```

Comment: ... what does not work? And please fix your indentation.

Comment: `Enter the name`, but you're checking against the month number!

Comment: for more economy of statements you could use fallthrough for the case statements - although this is not a good thing to do in professional code (error prone since you also could just have forgotten a break statement):

`case 12: case 1: case 2: season = "winter"; break;`

Answer (score 2):

As you are almost there, two tips to get you further:

> Write a program that prompts the user for a month name and then uses a switch to display the

So use:

```
String month = scanner.next();
```

to ask for a **string**; to then switch:

```
case "december" : ...
```

That is about it!

Besides, you might have to call `trim()` on the incoming string; and you also want to use `toLowerCase()` to ensure you dont run into "December" not being the same as "december".

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to all this, where would I put the String, trim(), and toLowerCase()

Comment: After the input is collected into a variable (String month in this case) and before the switch statement. You're basically cleaning up the input to a standardized format. So naturally, you'd want to do it after you got the input but before you use the input.

Comment: @michael You can either chain the functions and do `String month = scanner.next().trim().toLowerCase();` or you can add a separate statements after `String month = scanner.next();` like `month = month.trim();`.

Comment: @michael I left those details out *on purpose*. This is your *homework*. Just google words such as "java string trim" for example. You dont learn much when looking to other people to explain all the details.

Answer (score 1):

For economy of code statements you can use multiple case at the same time.

Take input

```
String month = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
```

Switch case

```
switch (month) {
        case "march":
        case "april":
        case "may":
            season = "spring";
            break;
        case "june":
        case "july":
        case "august":
            season = "summer";
            break;
```

Added trim and lowercase as suggested by @GhostCat

Comment: But that will always print out the month as a lowercase!

Comment: I actually suggested to let him find out himself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a switch on strings but if you want to keep this code, you need a function that will take a String like "June" and give you back 6 or "January" gives you back 12.

Answer (score 0):

**you have not declared season in the class try this it work **

```
public class Assignment4 {
private static Scanner input;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String season=null;
    System.out.println("Enter the name of a month");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    switch (month) {
      case 12: season = "winter"; break;
      case 1: season = "winter"; break;
      case 2: season = "winter"; break;
      case 3: season = "spring"; break;
      case 4: season = "spring"; break;
      case 5: season = "spring"; break;
      case 6: season = "summer"; break;
      case 7: season = "summer"; break;
      case 8: season = "summer"; break;
      case 9: season = "fall"; break;
      case 10: season = "fall"; break;
      case 11: season = "fall"; break;
      default: System.out.println("Error: invalid month.");

}   

         System.out.println("The season of the month " + month + "is " + season + ".");
    }}
```

out put for this is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the month:");
try{ // wrap with try-catch block in case user entered invalid input (not a number)
    int month = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); // it's better to read the entire line then parse it

    // use the ternary condition and one String variable
    String result = (month==1||month==2||month==12)  ? "The season of the month " + month + " is Winter."  :
                    (month==3||month==4||month==5)   ? "The season of the month " + month + " is Spring."  :
                    (month==6||month==7||month==8)   ? "The season of the month " + month + " is Summber." :
                    (month==9||month==10||month==11) ? "The season of the month " + month + " is Fall."    : "Error: invalid month.";

    System.out.println(result); // print out the result

   }catch(NumberFormatException e){ // if your program reaches this point that means it's not a number
        System.out.println("Error: invalid Input, Please use number only.");
   }
```

**Test**

```
Enter the month:
Text  ->  Error: invalid Input, Please use number only.
1     ->  The season of the month 1 is Winter.
5     ->  The season of the month 5 is Spring.
13    ->  Error: invalid month.
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are asked to use `switch` as a mandatory requirement, you can do something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the name of a month:");

String month = input.nextLine().trim(); // read the entire line and remove leading spaces by using trim() method


String result;
switch(month.toLowerCase()){
    case "january": case "february": case "december":
        result = "The season of the month " + month + " is Winter.";
    break;

    case "march": case "april": case "may":
        result = "The season of the month " + month + " is Spring.";
    break;

    case "jun": case "july": case "august":
        result = "The season of the month " + month + " is Summber.";
    break;

    case "september": case "october": case "november":
        result = "The season of the month " + month + " is Fall.";
    break;

    default: 
        result = "Error: invalid month.";
}


 System.out.println(result); // print out the result
```

**Test**

```
Enter the name of a month:
January     ->  The season of the month January is Winter.
APRIL       ->  The season of the month APRIL is Spring.    
Not a month ->  Error: invalid month.
```